# Finding xml text content from tag name in python

Tags: python, xml

I certain this type of question has been asked before, but I can't seem to get the right set of words to find the answer myself...

I've got an XML file, for example

```
<document>
   <page>
      <title>title1</title>
      <id>1</id>
      <text>this is text1</text>
   </page>
   <page>
      <title>title2</title>
      <id>2</id>
      <text>this is text2</text>
   </page>
   <page>
      <title>title3</title>
      <id>3</id>
      <comment>random comment</comment>
      <text>this is text3</text>
   </page>
</document>
```

I am trying to find a way to, ideally, store each values within  tags into an array.

Now I had originally tried just printing everything with the code below, but that only worked until the time where there is the random  tag which throws off the indexing. So, is there a way to simple get the text from  tag? Or is there an absolute need to know the array index?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('./xml_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print(child[2].text)
```

I apologies if this is common question, I really couldn't figure out any answers online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since from your question it sounds like you're looking to get a specific key, you can simple use `find(<key_name>).text` to get the contents of the XML key with that name

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('./all_foods.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for x in root:
    print x.find("title").text

>>>
   title1
   title2
   title3
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this is giving me "TypeError: 'ElementTree' object is not iterable."

Regardless, thanks for the help I will look into this find function. In the mean time I got an alternate answer from nick_gabpe which works. I do however appreciate this, more to learn is always great.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `for x in root` not `for x in tree`, it'll work if you change that

Comment: Super, works very nicely and even keeps the text formatting I wanted. Thanks so much!

Comment: Does this still work? I appear to have an issue that x.find(string) returns None on items that don't match the search string, which then causes an error when trying to get the .text attribute. Thus it just crashes. Can't think of a nice way around this without having a massive sequences of try:except: blocks (I'm needing to access several different named tags in a single file)

Answer (score 4):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('./all_foods.xml')
my_text = [item.text for item in tree.iter()]
```

This will give you list of text that you want. If you want some specific text you can use

```
my_tags = [item.text for item in tree.iter() if item.text == "title1"]
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You saved my life! How to find value using the tag. For ex: id, I need the id value.