# Python code to find and replace xml subtag text

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

I have a xml file below and I need tofind and replace xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax tags by adding 10 or performing some arithmetic operations to it.I am new to python with xml file.

The xml file is below:

```
    <annotation>
    <folder>stomatitis</folder>
    <filename>stomatitis427.jpg</filename>
    <path>/Volumes/Windows/tongue-img/stomatitis/stomatitis427.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>2992</width>
        <height>2000</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>stomatitis</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1324</xmin>
            <ymin>677</ymin>
            <xmax>1404</xmax>
            <ymax>783</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>stomatitis</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1610</xmin>
            <ymin>643</ymin>
            <xmax>1670</xmax>
            <ymax>720</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

I need to replace all the xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax tags text value and save the updated xml file.
I tried this code but it gives error:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
        tree = ET.parse('/Users/sripdeep/Desktop/Tongue_Cancer/leuko32.xml')  
        root = tree.getroot()
        x=10
        n_xmin=str(xmin-x)
        n_ymin=str(ymin-x)
        n_xmax=str(xmax-x)
        n_ymax=str(ymax-x)
        for elem in root.getiterator():
            try:
                elem.text = elem.text.replace(str(xmin),n_xmin)
                elem.text = elem.text.replace(str(ymin),n_ymin)
                elem.text = elem.text.replace(str(xmax),n_xmax)
                elem.text = elem.text.replace(str(ymax),n_ymax)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        tree.write(open('C2.xml', 'wb'))
```

Values are not updated in the new created xml file.

I also tried this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('/Users/sripdeep/Desktop/Tongue_Cancer/leuko32.xml')  
root = tree.getroot()
for i in root:
    print (i.find("xmin").text)
```

Which also gives error as:

```
print (i.find("xmin").text)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: It seems remarkably straightforward. The error message tells you the problem. You already know how to convert things to `str` type, since you're doing it in your code. What is the difficulty here?

Comment: i think elem.text = elem.text.replace(xmin,n_xmin) works for replacing only text values but I have integers in my case on which i am performing some operation

Comment: I tried (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089578/finding-xml-text-content-from-tag-name-in-python) but it shows error

Comment: @jpmc26 the error is solved but the new values are not updated in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet, you use undefined variables, such as `xmin` in `n_xmin=str(xmin-x)`.

In the second snippet, you try to find the `xmin` child of every child of the root. No such elements exist in the XML document. The `xmin` elements are located further down in the hierarchy.

---

The following code adds 10 to the integer value of the `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax`, and `ymax` elements.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('leuko32.xml')  

wanted = ["xmin", "ymin", "xmax", "ymax"]

for elem in tree.iter():
    if elem.tag in wanted:
        elem.text = str(int(elem.text) + 10)

tree.write('C2.xml')
```

Comment: They're not undefined according to the error message. They're just not defined in the posted code. This might be a reason to vote to close as not having an MCVE, but it's definitely not part of the answer.

Comment: My code does "replace xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax tags by adding 10" as requested. Why is that not the answer?

Comment: According to the question, the first snippet "gives error" (no specific error message provided). The second snippet produces "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'". What is the problem?

Comment: I agree with @mzjn. Helpful answer.

Comment: @mzjn I said it wasn't part of the answer. I didn't say your later portions weren't.